# Is this CSP implementation is secure?

Tags: penetration-test, content-security-policy

I face a CSP header something like this -

`default-src https:; font-src https: data:; img-src https: data:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline';`

So is this is secure implementation?

This includes `https:` so should I consider that `https://anyurlallowed`?

Comment: Answer down below. I wanted to ask, what made you think this *was* secure?

Comment: Thanks actually I wasn;t 100% sure what exactly https: means.

Comment: You can find proper documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, this is not safe.

The fact that your `script-src` includes `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'` means that it provides no defense against Cross-Site Scripting.

Furthermore, `https:` does indeed mean it allows inclusion of any source using https, such as `https://attackercontrolleddomainfromwhichyoudefinitelyshouldneverexecuteanyjavascriptfrom.com`